# A parameter in swiftmailer to disable email delivery

Tags: swiftmailer

Is there a way to tell SwiftMailer to actually disable email delivery?

Use case:

1. I have a development environment and instead of actually sending test emails (that have to be cleaned-up) I would like to stringify `\Swift_Message` and send it to log device.
2. In staging or production delivery will be enabled.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I suppose one can always skip forming mail transport in dev environment... But a parameter would be cleaner.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/dev_environment.html#disabling-sending? swiftmailer.disable_delivery?

Comment: Looks like a new feature.

Comment: yup seems like since 2.3 version